# Process byte arrays correctly Encoding Utf-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, webclient

I am trying to download a PDF file and encode it in UTF-8 format and then transform it back into a Base64 to attach it to a MailMessage, however I get an exception when passing the string to Base64.

exception
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character...

my code...

```
  try
            {
                if (attachment.Uri.Contains("http") || attachment.Uri.Contains("https"))
                {
                    byte[] contentByte = null;
                    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        Uri uri = new Uri(attachment.Uri);
                        contentByte = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
                    }


                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(contentByte);

                    String fullString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
                    String stringData = fullString.Split(',')[1];
                    byte[] byteData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringData);
                    
                    MemoryStream streamData = new MemoryStream(byteData);
                    Attachment attachmentDoc = new Attachment(streamData, fileName);

                    mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentDoc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                notificationLog.Error.Write(String.Format("Sendmail error. Attachment not found: " + attachment.FileName));
            }
```

Comment: I see you are doing a string operation of Split.  String stringData = fullString.Split(',')[1];  so after this you may get the new byte array as  byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this the wrong way.

You are trying to *decode* the PDF as UTF-8 (which it is not) to UTF-16, and then *decode* that UTF-16 as Base64 (which it is not) to a byte array, then attach those bytes to the email. That is the complete opposite of what you need.

Base64 operates on bytes, not strings/characters. There is no need to *encode* a PDF (a binary file) to UTF-8 before *encoding* it in Base64. Just *encode* the PDF bytes as-is straight to Base64, eg:

```cs
try
{
    if (attachment.Uri.StartsWith("http:") || attachment.Uri.StartsWith("https:"))
    {
        byte[] contentByte = null;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            Uri uri = new Uri(attachment.Uri);
            contentByte = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
        }

        String stringData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(contentByte);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData));

        Attachment attachmentDoc = new Attachment(memStream, fileName);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentDoc);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    notificationLog.Error.Write(String.Format("Sendmail error. Attachment not found: " + attachment.FileName));
}
```

However, using this approach, the receiver won't be able to decode the PDF correctly, because it won't know the PDF bytes were encoded in Base64.

Fortunately, the `Attachment` class can handle the Base64 for you, and notify the receiver of the encoding. Just give the `Attachment` the raw PDF bytes as-is, and set its [`TransferEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachmentbase.transferencoding?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Mail_AttachmentBase_TransferEncoding) property to `Base64`, eg:

```cs
try
{
    if (attachment.Uri.StartsWith("http:") || attachment.Uri.StartsWith("https:"))
    {
        byte[] contentByte = null;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            Uri uri = new Uri(attachment.Uri);
            contentByte = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
        }

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(contentByte);

        Attachment attachmentDoc = new Attachment(memStream, fileName);
        attachmentDoc.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentDoc);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    notificationLog.Error.Write(String.Format("Sendmail error. Attachment not found: " + attachment.FileName));
}
```

Comment: I was honestly researching, because I don't know this part of the programming, it was exactly my conclusion from what I researched ... would it be the same case for the docx format? @Remy

Comment: @JoseAyala what I said applies to ALL files you want to attach to the email.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much for taking the time to respond...